# Using a Play view from coffeescript

Tags: playframework, coffeescript

I am using the play framework.  I have a coffeescript query that returns a list of objects, on which I want to do some moderately complicated rendering.  The rendering would be much easier and clearer to write in a .scala.html file than in coffee script.  Is there a way to access files in the view from coffee script?

Basically, I want something like this

**app/views/index.scala.html**

```
@()
<script type='text/javascript' src='@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/index.js")'></script>
<div id="widgets"/>
```

**app/assets/javascripts/index.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $.get "/widgets", (widgets) ->
    $.each widgets, (index, widget) ->
       $("#widgets").append ??views.widget(widget)
```

??views.widget does not work, but I do not know what to replace it with.

**app/views/widget.scala.html**

```
@(widget: Widget) 
Foo: @widget.foo<br>
Bar: <b>@widget.bar</b><br>
Baz: @widget.baz<br>
```

In short, the coffeescript does a request, which gets a list of objects, which are  passed to a view for rendering.  I am not attached to that workflow, but (from what I understand of Play), it seems like the obvious and best way to do it.  If there is a different workflow that accomplishes what I am trying to do, I am happy to learn that instead.

To be clear, if `/widgets` returns two widgets, with `foo,bar,baz` equal to `1,2,3` and `a,b,c`, I want this to be the final result:

```
<script ....></script>
<div id=widgets>
Foo: 1<br>
Bar: <b>2</b><br>
Baz: 3<br>
Foo: a<br>
Bar: <b>b</b><br>
Baz: c<br>
</div>
```

I am using play 2.4, but there is not yet a play 2.4 tag, and I don't think I have enough reputation to create it.

Comment: Really interesting question. On the one hand `widget.scala.html` must be a compiled function somewhere. But it's not that obvious that it is possible for the front end to access it. It surely executes on the server (controller) end to do the rendering? But there could be some hints in dynamic page loading discussions like [this](https://thomasheuring.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/scala-playframework-2-04-get-pages-dynamically/) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/lcfFe2gOx5Y). Perhaps a controller method that returns the rendered html for the coffeescript to insert...?